# Webpage setup time in Android WebView

Tags: android, http, web

currently Iam developing an app that measures web page loading time, number of (and size of) resources included etc.

One thing I'm still missing is "setup time", that is a time from clicking on "start measuring" button, to the time when the first bytes of the page are being loaded.

So far, I've tried this by measuring this time by noticing the system milisecond time after clicking on the button, then noticing the time of onPageStarted event to get this setup time.

I thought Im fine, but recently Ive found out, that if I want to measure several web pages like this (I always clear the webview before by calling stopLoading and loading about:blank), I see that this setup time is drastically lower than during the loading of the first page.

Example values:

```
Setup Time (www.google.com): 0.156s
Setup Time (www.manwe.cz): 0.05s
Setup Time (www.anothersite.com): 0.007s
Setup Time (www.reddit.com): 0.025s
```

etc.

First of all - why is the time so different, 
and second - any ideas how I could measure properly this setup time? (since this is clearly not correct).

Just a note: it doesnt matter which site I load first/second etc... (that means it doesnt matter if I load google.com first, then reddit.com second or vice versa, the idea is that the first page that is loaded has a significantly higher "setup time")

edit: pieces of code

custom webViewClient

```
  private WebViewClient myWebViewClient = new WebViewClient() {

    public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
        setupTime = (System.currentTimeMillis()-startTime)/1000.0;
        startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    }               

    public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url){
        pageLoaded();
        endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    }
}
```

using myWebView client

```
public void StartURL(){ 

    setupTime = 0.0;
    endTime = (long) 0;
    startTime = (long) 0;   

    startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    activity.wv.setWebViewClient(myWebViewClient);      
    currentURL = URLList.remove(0);
    activity.wv.loadUrl( currentURL );
}
```

after everything is finished i use

```
activity.wv.stopLoading();
activity.wv.setWebViewClient(clearWebClient);
activity.wv.loadUrl("about:blank");
```

and clearWebClient is

```
private WebViewClient clearWebClient = new WebViewClient() {

    public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url){
        StartURL();
    }

};
```

which basically just re-starts the process of StartURL to process another web

Comment: my guess is that you are re-using a webview that is started up (WebViewClient setting) by going to the first link.  got code?

Comment: @petey added code... I re-use WebViewClient, should I make a new instance of it every time?